# If $s(c)=t(c)$ in $F(c)$ where $s(x)$ and $t(x)$ have degree $<n$ prove that $s(x)=t(x)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $F$ be a field and $c$ be a root of some $p(x)$ in some extenion of $F$. If $s(c)=t(c)$ in $F(c)$ where $s(x)$ and $t(x)$ have degree $<n$ prove that $s(x)=t(x)$.

I think I would use the division algorithm and show $s(x)/p(x)=p(c)q(c)+r(c)$. Then from a previously proved theorem, $p(c)q(c)+r(c)\in F(c)$ and any element of $F(c)$ can be written as $r(c)$. Do I seem to be on the right track? If so I am unsure of how to continue (which leads me to believe that I am off track)

Comment: What is $n$? The degree of the field extension? If so, are you familiar with minimal polynomials?

Comment: @MeesdeVries Yes I am. But not enough so to use them in the general sense, i.e. use them for some abstract $s(x)$